# Skip a step when restart a job in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

currently i am working on a task using spring batch.

there is a job which contains 3 steps: step1, step2, step3.

The first execution: step1, step2, step3.

If step2 is fail, we will restart the job.

but the second time, we want the job skip step2, that means: step1, step3.

Does anyone have a solution with **skip a specific step when restart a job**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JobRepository` interface to query about a step (there is a `JobRepository.getStepExecutionCount()` method); with a `JobExecutionDecider` you can flow to step2 or step3 based upon `JobRepository.getStepExecutionCount()` result

Comment: Thanks, I ready find a workaround solution to do that. I just add a flag in properties file, if I want to hack step2 when restart the job, just change flag in properties file.